# VBA Production and Control for Flashy, Blinky, Shifty, Active, Range-Selection-Border

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007, eventhandler, vba

The application that I am programming could benefit from a border, like those that are induced when selecting a range.  I don't know the official Microsoft-name for the border-type, but it looks like flashy, blinky, shifty dashes.  It would help the user to know (or remember after being interrupted by a co-worker) what cell-range they are supposed to be working with.  I would be embarrassed to admit how much time I think I've spent researching and trying to produce this border.  It includes all day, yesterday and 3 or 4 other focused trials.

One that seemed to produce a reasonable result with small range-selections is as follows - but again, only small selections and it causes excel to have to "think" for a while after execution, before surrendering control to the user:

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub test()
    Dim i_index As Long
    Dim Selec As Range

    Set Selec = Application.InputBox("Select a range to make a flashy, blinky border.", _
                                 "Select Range", _
                                 Type:=8)

    For i_index = 1 To 50

        If Selec.Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone Or Selec.Borders.LineStyle = xlDashDot Then
            With Selec
                .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlDashDotDot
                .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlDashDotDot
                .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDashDotDot
                .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlDashDotDot
            End With
        ElseIf Selec.Borders.LineStyle = xlDashDotDot Then
            With Selec
                .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlDashDot
                .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlDashDot
                .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDashDot
                .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlDashDot
            End With
        End If

        Sleep 500    'wait 0.5 seconds

    Next i_index
End Sub
```

The following seemed to provide a more stable time-delay:

```
 Sub SD(LenTime)
    Dim Start
    Start = Timer + LenTime
    Do While Timer < Start
        If Timer = 0 Then
            Start = Timer + 1
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

But, when I try to implement it with a handler:

```
Public Sub CodeInst_StartFlashyBorder(ByVal Selection As Range)
    Call StartFlashyBorder(Selection)
End Sub

Public Sub CodeInst_StopFlashyBorder(ByVal Selection As Range)
    Call StopFlashyBorder(Selection)
End Sub

Private Sub StartFlashyBorder(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone Or Target.Borders.LineStyle _
        = xlDashDot Then
        With Target
            .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlDashDotDot
            .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlDashDotDot
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDashDotDot
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlDashDotDot
        End With
    ElseIf Target.Borders.LineStyle = xlDashDotDot Then
        With Target
            .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlDashDot
            .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlDashDot
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDashDot
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlDashDot
        End With
    End If

    SD 0.25

    Application.OnTime Now, "StartFlashyBorder", , True

End Sub

Private Sub StopFlashyBorder(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
    Application.OnTime Now, "StartFlashyBorder", , False
End Sub
```

I am, thus far, not able to produce the desired behavior to integrate into my program.  I want my regular code to be able to do stuff while the handler is producing the flashy, blinky, shifty border.  For example, the code I tried to use to check its behavior is:

```
Sub TestBorder()

    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim r2 As Range
    Dim r3 As Range

    Set r1 = Application.InputBox("Select cell-range #1 and click OK.", _
                                  "Make Selection", _
                                  Type:=8)

    Call CodeInst_StartFlashyBorder(r1)

    Set r2 = Application.InputBox("Select cell-range #2 and click OK.", _
                                  "Make Selection", _
                                  Type:=8)

    Call CodeInst_StartFlashyBorder(r1)

    Set r3 = Application.InputBox("Select cell-range #3 and click OK.", _
                                  "Make Selection", _
                                  Type:=8)

    Call CodeInst_StartFlashyBorder(r1)

    If Application.InputBox("Enter 0 to turn off cell-range #1.", _
                            "Enter Choice", _
                            Type:=1) = 0 Then
        Call CodeInst_StopFlashyBorder(r1)
    End If

    If Application.InputBox("Enter 0 to turn off cell-range #2.", _
                            "Enter Choice", _
                            Type:=1) = 0 Then
        Call CodeInst_StopFlashyBorder(r2)
    End If

    If Application.InputBox("Enter 0 to turn off cell-range #3.", _
                            "Enter Choice", _
                            Type:=1) = 0 Then
        Call CodeInst_StopFlashyBorder(r3)
    End If

End Sub
```

I am not very experienced at coding handlers.  I pretty much went 15 years without coding in any language and handlers were a weakness for me then.  But, I have made a lot of progress with an ambitious little project.  I want to be able to control the flashy, blinky, shifty border for use in the program.  Does anyone care to share how they produce this border-style in their code.  Is it possible in VBA?  Thank you.

Comment: Are you after a replication of the so-called "Marching Ants" border you see when you hit "Ctrl+C" / Copy?

Comment: "Marching Ants" - Yes, that name seems accurate.  I am trying to achieve that or anything with very similar visual effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Loop,  the code would be like this
Selec.Offset(i_index - 1)

```
Sub test()
    Dim i_index As Long
    Dim Selec As Range

    Set Selec = Application.InputBox("Select a range to make a flashy, blinky border.", _
                                 "Select Range", _
                                 Type:=8)

    For i_index = 1 To 50
        With Selec.Offset(i_index - 1)
            If .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone Or .Borders.LineStyle = xlDashDot Then

                    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlDashDotDot
                    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlDashDotDot
                    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDashDotDot
                    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlDashDotDot

            ElseIf .Borders.LineStyle = xlDashDotDot Then

                    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlDashDot
                    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlDashDot
                    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDashDot
                    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlDashDot

            End If
        End With
        'Sleep 500    'wait 0.5 seconds

    Next i_index
End Sub
```